# GCC equivalent of PDBs

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, gcc

I have a program that I intend to distribute to end users, and would like to have receive crash reports from them. If I were using MSVC, I would generate minidumps and have those sent to me, and then inspect them with the corresponding PDB to get a useful stack trace, at the very least.

What is the equivalent of doing this with GCC? I can generate a stack trace, but if I want this to be useful, it requires having debug symbols compiled into the executable (with -g). Obviously this is unacceptable for release distribution, since the executable can balloon in size quite a bit.

I googled a bit and found references to objcopy being able to separate out debug symbols to a separate file, but that page implied I would still need to have the debug symbols available alongside the release executable, which again is obviously unacceptable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I couldn't find an exact answer to this, but I found an alternate solution that works just as well: Compile with optimization and other release flags alongside `-g`, store the resulting executable somewhere, then remove debug symbols using `strip`. Ship the stripped executable, and when you get a stack trace, use `addr2line` in combination with the original, unstripped executable, and you should get all the symbols back.

Answer (score 14):

Well the idea is that you compile with `-g` to add debug symbols but not slow the program down, ie. most programs will do `-g -O2` then you can seperate debug symbols with `objdump`. After that you can `strip` your release build so it won't have any debug symbols.

Update: Recent gdb supports separate debug files, see https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html

For example you can doo

```
objcopy --only-keep-debug prog prog.debug
strip prog
```

Now your `prog` won't have any debug symbols. But you can use `proc.debug` file to debug it in gdb.

Comment: That's well and nice, but how do I reconcile a stack trace generated without debug symbols (and thus containing only addresses) with the separated debug symbols later, to get a stack trace that I can actually read?

Comment: gdb can set to use seperate debug symbols this is how Linux distributions enable debug, see http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html

Comment: This page likewise seems to assume that the debugging information is present on the computer where the fault is manifesting. I'll clarify: we cannot ship debug information to our clients. It has to be possible for the software to generate a stack trace (without debug symbols) and for this stack trace to be reconciled with separate debug symbols on one of our development computers here at a later stage, without further involvement from the client. I should perhaps also clarify that this is a Windows environment, not a *nix one.

Comment: If you produce a coredump you can re-run it on gdb with debug symbols, isn't that what you are after?

Comment: MinGW does not include dbghelp and thus it is not possible for me to produce minidumps. Even if I could, can gcc handle minidumps? (As opposed to core dumps -- these are Windows systems, to reiterate.)

Comment: Looks like something like http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/DrMingw is needed.

Comment: DrMinGW is well and good, and in fact I use its exception handler to generate a stack trace -- but again, DrMinGW can only produce useful stack traces if the executable has debug symbols available on the system where it crashes, which is not the case here. It must be possible to post-mortem reconcile debug symbols with a stack trace from a stripped executable...

Comment: Well the only way I can see is that converting minidump to something GDB can understand. Sorry!